# PHP: exec() - replace process

Tags: php, process, exec

Is it possible with PHP to execute a command and thereby replace the current process?
Like in C or Ruby:

```
exec('ls')
# should not get here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pcntl_exec`: http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php

Comment: This is what i was looking for. The only problem was that this function needs full paths to binaries. I wanted to preload a library when launching an interactive php shell. It's now `pcntl_exec($_SERVER['_'], array('-ad', 'auto_prepend_file=/path/to/library'))`. The `$_SERVER['_']` is the path to the php interpreter.